# how can i make the parent start working when the child process paused? c programming

Tags: c, linux, wait, waitpid

I tried to use waitpid, but I'm stuck at how can I achieve that.
because i want to  `kill(childID, SIGCONT);` from the parent and make the child do something  without kalling it (with continue)
but rather stop it and when i "child is stopped" the parent should continue working. the child continued  from the parent and the parent shall wait until it's `pause()` (child)

Comment: Maybe look at message passing instead of signals

Comment: @stark i need to use Ordinary pipe and it's important that the child live in a loop and they communicate via this pipe ... on demand when the parent sends data it should process the data and sends back the results --- I figured out why not use Unix signals to stop and continue the child on demand .. and it's important that i have only one child

Comment: To make the parent work when the child is stopped, you should do absolutely nothing.  If the parent has work to be done, it will be scheduled.  If it is blocking on something, you'll need to figure out why it's blocked.  If the parent is calling `waitpid` then it is waiting for the child to terminate, and will not proceed until that happens.  So maybe you need to remove the call to waitpid.  But many details are missing from the question.